# what is the data type that I want to use to send set of objects with a web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, wsdl

It is not possible to use `ArrayList as return type` for @webservice method. How can I send set of objects with @webmethod to a webservice clients? I am using java web services with JBoss 5.0 AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send Object arrays using java web services.But before sending the objects with web services we need to tell java that how to convert them into XML (responses are returned as XML messages) . You can use JAXB for this conversion. All you have to do is add

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "some_name")
```

before the class names that you are going to return. Then your return values are converted to XML with appropriate tags( Object attribute names)

Comment: Prashna ahala thamanma aewata uththara daana nondi wade witharak karanna epa

Comment: @thilinarmtb kawuruth daanne naththam ithn mamawath daganna epay